# R: Recoding Variables Across Multiple Objects

Tags: r, data-manipulation

Thank you in advance for your advice. I am trying to create a new variable over multiple objects in a loop. These new variables are generated by a function.

For example, I have three sets of country-level data:

```
# Generate Example Data
`enter code here`pop <- data.frame(country=c("US","US","CA","CA","FR","FR"),year=c(1,2,1,2,1,2),value=c(290,300,29,30,50,55))
gas <- data.frame(country=c("US","US","CA","CA","FR","FR"),year=c(1,2,1,2,1,2),value=c(3.10,1.80,4.50,2.50,4.50,2.50))
cars <- data.frame(country=c("US","US","CA","CA","FR","FR"),year=c(1,2,1,2,1,2),value=c(2.1,2.2,1.8,1.9,1.3,1.3))
```

I want to create a new variable, called “countrycode”, using the countrycode() command in the countrycode package.

I would perform the operation on individual objects like this:

```
library(countrycode)
pop$ccode <- countrycode(pop$country,"iso2c","cown")
pop$id <- (pop$ccode*10000)+pop$year
```

But I have a large number of objects. I was hoping to do this over a loop, like this

```
# Create list of variables
vars <- c("pop","gas","cars")
for (i in vars){
  i$ccode <- countrycode(country,"iso2c","cown")
  i$id <- (i$ccode*10000)+i$year
}
```

But that doesn’t work. I’ve been trying to do this using **assign()** in loops and **apply()**, but I’m too dense to get my head around how to make this work in my case.

If someone could provide me with an example of how to do this with my own type of data, I’d be very grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Special thanks to @Pawel for supplying the missing information needed to solve the problem.  The solution was:

```
rm(list=ls())
pop <- data.frame(country=c("US","US","CA","CA","FR","FR"),year=c(1,2,1,2,1,2),value=c(290,300,29,30,50,55))
gas <- data.frame(country=c("US","US","CA","CA","FR","FR"),year=c(1,2,1,2,1,2),value=c(3.10,1.80,4.50,2.50,4.50,2.50))
cars <- data.frame(country=c("US","US","CA","CA","FR","FR"),year=c(1,2,1,2,1,2),value=c(2.1,2.2,1.8,1.9,1.3,1.3))


attachCodes <- function(dframe)
{
  df <- dframe
  df$ccode <- countrycode(df$country,"iso2c","cown")
  df$id <- (df$ccode*10000)+df$year
  return(df)
}

names <- list("pop","gas","cars")
for(i in names){
  assign(i,attachCodes(get(i)))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Would this work for you?

```
pop <- data.frame(country=c("US","US","CA","CA","FR","FR"),year=c(1,2,1,2,1,2),value=c(290,300,29,30,50,55))
gas <- data.frame(country=c("US","US","CA","CA","FR","FR"),year=c(1,2,1,2,1,2),value=c(3.10,1.80,4.50,2.50,4.50,2.50))
cars <- data.frame(country=c("US","US","CA","CA","FR","FR"),year=c(1,2,1,2,1,2),value=c(2.1,2.2,1.8,1.9,1.3,1.3))


attachCodes <- function(dframe)
{
  df <- dframe
  df$ccode <- countrycode(df$country,"iso2c","cown")
  df$id <- (df$ccode*10000)+df$year
  return(df)
}

tablesList <- list(pop,gas,cars)
tablesList <- lapply(tablesList,attachCodes)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I appreciate the help.  The problem is that **tablesList** can get very unwieldy when you do this to 50+ larger data tables.  I do'nt really know what do to with the table.  Is there a way to change the original objects **pop**, **gas**, **cars**?